# Error in Data Processing in Gensim LDA using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gensim, lda

I am using Gensim LDA for the topic modelling. I am using pandas DataFrame for the processing. but I am getting an error

> TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, Series found

I need to process data using Pandas only, input data is like (one row)

```
 PMID           Text
12755608    The DNA complexation and condensation properties
12755609    Three proteins namely protective antigen PA edition
12755610    Lecithin retinol acyltransferase LRAT catalyze
```

My code is

```
data = pd.read_csv("h1.csv", delimiter = "\t")
data = data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Text'])
data['Index'] = data.index
data["Text"] = data['Text'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
data.head()

def lemmatize_stemming(text):
    return stemmer.stem(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(text, pos='v'))

def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token):
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result


input_data = data.Text.str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')
print('\n\n tokenized and lemmatized document: ')
print(preprocess(input_data))
```

Comment: Based on the error message, I guess your function requires a string, like "The DNA complexation and condensation properties". Instead, you are supplying the function with a pandas.Series. Without dummy data it is hard to figure out exactly where your error pops up and how exactly you can solve it

Comment: @KenHBS  I have updated the data, remaining rows are similar, yes I need to pass a string, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
def preprocess(text):
   result = []
   for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
      if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token) > 2:
         result.append(token)
   return result

doc_processed = input_data['Text'].map(preprocess)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_processed)
#to prepapre a document term matrix
doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_processed]

#Lda model
Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
#Lda model to get the num_topics, number of topic required, 
#passses is the number training do you want to perform
ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=2, id2word = dictionary, passes=2)
result=ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=5, num_words=15)
```

Comment: can you please add a bit more explanation to it, I am having same error but have used my own preprocessing docode, which holds good for training but not for testing a single unseen doc.

Comment: depends on your data, can you post your code and sample data?